# Passing argument to gitlab-ci.yml via gitlab-runner

Tags: docker, gitlab

I'd like to pass an environmental variable I've already got set in my session (`MY_VAR`) to `gitlab-runner exec`:

```
sudo gitlab-runner exec docker --docker-privileged --env MY_VAR=$MY_VAR test
```

I'd like to use it in my `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
before_script:
  - echo $MY_VAR
```

It isn't passing. :(

Answer (score -1):

This was a total mistake. I forgot to restart my terminal. The MY_VAR was not exported in the terminal session I had open when testing this.